# How to debug spring cacheable?

Tags: java, spring

We are trying to figure out how to tell whether spring's annotation "@Cacheable" is working or not. So far we've been debugging the application (running the IDE in debug's mode), and what we can see is that we are actually getting within the method's implementation. Wasn't that exactly not supposed to happen? Considered that it is cached.

Comment: How was the object instantiated ? A common mistake is to use "new" and create object. As long as the spring bean is created using application context , you could add a log statement or print to check if execution reaches inside the function .

Comment: You could also enable log4j for spring packages to view the detailed spring bean execution functionality

Answer (score 2):

The debugging turn out to be as expected (i.e. the cached method "should skip" once is effectively chached). The issue probed to be an environment misconfiguration in the application's environment.

Comment: What specifically was the issue?

Comment: My problem was, that I was calling `@Cacheable` method by other method within same class. Extracting method with `@Cacheable` annotation to separate class enabled caching.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by simply Autowiring the cacheManager.
And then adding this code

```
Object cached = cacheManager.getCache([your cache name]).get([your_cache_key]);
if (cached == null) {
     cached = cachableAnnotatedMethod();
     cacheManager.getCache([your cache name]).put([your cache key], cached);
}
```

I know this is pretty naive as cacheable might work different, but would take you to the point on most of the cases.

Comment: Maybe naive but simple and working. Thanks +1